# How can I display scaled images without losing clarity?

Tags: android, image-scaling, android-imageview

I have to display small thumbnail images for my ListView, with the full image on a detail screen.

I'm using the same image for the two layouts. Here is my list item `<ImageView>`:

```
<ImageView android:layout_height="50dip"                             
    android:layout_width="50dip" 
    android:id="@+id/item_view_img" 
    android:scaleType="fitXY">
</ImageView>
```

Here is my detail view's `<ImageView>`:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/update_details_img"
    android:layout_width="289dip" android:layout_height="206dip"
    android:src="@drawable/q_silhouette" android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" android:gravity="center">                                     
</ImageView>
```

The original image size is about 300x360. Neither of my image displays are looking good.
How can I show these images without losing clarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is not as much an Android question as it is a 2D graphics question. Currently there are many graphics gurus trying to solve the exact problem you are having.

It is impossible to change image dimensions without losing fidelity from the original. The issue really is whether or not that loss in fidelity results in loss of clarity. Most often, the answer is as fidelity goes down, so does clarity. There are many ways to mitigate this, however.

As a general rule of thumb, you may downsize an image to about 1/2 the original size without artifacts. After this is accomplished, you may often downsize one more time depending upon the complexity of the image (number of colors).

Alternatively, you may upsize an image to approximately 1.75 the original. You can almost never cheat the system by upsizing again.

All bets are off, however, if you change the aspect ratio. This is because it will distort the image in other ways. In Android, you may avoid changing the aspect ratio in XML by setting the `scaleType` attribute to `centerInside` value. This will help considerably and keep the image within the bounds. You should especially do this for your thumbnail `ImageView`, unless you are going to set it with the same aspect ratio as the detailed `ImageView`.

Comment: Hi @Fuzzical Logic, I have added `centerInside` to my `<ImageView>`. but the image is not displaying in the mentioned width(289dip), height(206dip).. it is displaying very small...

`<ImageView android:id="@+id/update_details_img"
 android:layout_width="289dip" android:layout_height="206dip"
 android:src="@drawable/q_silhouette" android:paddingTop="10dp"
 android:scaleType="centerInside" android:gravity="center">          
</ImageView>`

Comment: Yet, theoriginal is 300 x 360? What is the actual size that shows up? Are you able to get that?

Comment: this time my image actual size is 800x600.. still it is displaying in small size.. even by using  `android:layout_width="800dip" android:layout_height="600dip"` in my layout.. margin size is increasing but image is still displaying very small. seems like it is 50x50.

Comment: At 800 x 600, your 50x50dip will render it very small. Your 289x206 should have a top and bottom margin, but should be alright to view. Something else is going on here. It is not the "centerInside" that is causing the problem, it is something else related to the image. centerInside simply shrinks the image according to the smallest relative dimension of the container.

Comment: If it is displaying your 50x50 thumbnail, then you must be using the reference to the adjusted 50x50 image rather than reloading the image with the new dimensions. You'll have to look at the code.

Comment: just for clarification... I'm not loading any thumbnail version.. i have only one image whose dim. is 800x600, and I'm loading it but it is looking very small (say 50x50 aprox). no where i have specified like 50x50.

Comment: Then there is an error in the code, Venkat. centerInside gets its dimension from whatever calculations you make, either by XML, override onMeasure or onLayout, or by setting dimensions explicity. Have you considered posting some of the code, so we can see it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are changing the ratios with these different ImageViews, you may want to scale with `centerInside` or `centerCrop`.